# HTML how to stop users from typing dates larger than 2100-01-01?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following input field:

```html
<input type="date" min="2020-11-04" max="2100-01-01"/>
```

This works perfectly fine to restrict dates from `2020-11-04` till `2100-01-01` in the date picker. However, it's still possible for the user to enter a date larger or smaller than the specified `min` and `max` by typing in the input field.

Is there a way I can prevent this client-side using HTML and/or with JavaScript, so the user can't type in a date larger or smaller than the specified `min` and `max`? I would like to keep the date picker that comes with `<input type="date">`, so I'm unsure if using a regex pattern would be the right way to go about this.

Comment: rather than limiting what the user can do - perhaps forcus on proividing a validation message if the entered value does not meet with the input pattern you want to have. I would show the bvalidation message on the blur of the ffield - not waiting until form submission.

Comment: You can validate it and in the submit just show a validation message.
Check here.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min

Comment: Yes the user can type it, but have you tested what happens when you try to submit the form with invalid input?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol -I would disable the submit / [prevent the user from being able to submit the form - with approapriate guidance text to explain why they cannot submit. What is the virtue in allowing the form to be submitted with invalid input values - better to tell them what is wrong and how to fix it before the submision can proceed. IMO

Comment: @gavgrif Have you actually tried submitting a form with an out-of-bounds value?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes I have tried that, it only works on a <input type="submit">, but I don't see that message if I have <button> and where I use javascript to submit it.

Comment: Why are you using a `<button>` to submit a form? Even if it's JavaScript doing it, you should be listening to `submit` on the form, not `click` on a button.

Answer (score 2):

You can "prevent" the keydown events in the input field. That would force the user to use the date picker.

Here I added a class to the input and used `querySelectorAll` in case you have more than one field to affect.

While I quite agree with @gavgriff about his advice to validate fields... Your question was **"How to stop users from typing"** ;)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".noTyping").forEach(el=>{
  el.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
  })
})
```

```html
<input class="noTyping" type="date" min="2020-11-04" max="2100-01-01"/>
```

Comment: You could this with a targetted selecteor without adding a class - "document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]')".... - but I would strongly recommend against this approach - it is very confusing for the user to interact with the field and not have the value update on the keystroke - but not have any guidance / info as why itis not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this simple working script to make a smooth date typer which is going to fix your problem and gives a better experience.
You can try and use the up/down arrows on your keyboard to see how it works when the picked date is higher/less than the conditions.

```js
const customDateLimiter = input => {
  let conditionDates = {
    min: new Date(input.min),
    max: new Date(input.max)
  }
  const currentDate = new Date(input.value);

  if( currentDate < conditionDates.min ) 
    input.value = conditionDates.min.toLocaleDateString().replaceAll("/", "-").split("-").reverse().join("-").toString();
  //console.log(  currentDate < conditionDates.min );
  
  if( currentDate > conditionDates.max ) 
    input.value = conditionDates.max.toLocaleDateString().replaceAll("/", "-").split("-").reverse().join("-").toString();
  //console.log(  currentDate > conditionDates.max );
  
  return input.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" min="2020-11-04" max="2100-01-01" onchange="customDateLimiter(this)" />
```